# Is it possible to have different numbers of viewControllers for iPod and iPad using only one storyboard in an universal app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I want to make an universal app and I understand I can make one storyboard to design it, adapting the views for each possible device.
My app should be a tabbed application.
When I create my project, I have a Tab Bar Controller and two View Controllers I can adapt for iPhone or iPad.

Is it possible to design it to get for instance, four View Controllers for iPhone, and only two for iPad?

Regards,

Olivier

Comment: What exactly do you mean by  **_four View Controllers for iPhone, and only two for iPad_**?

Comment: no this is not possible. using size class but you can do this by programatically create a tabbarcontroller  class and assign the viewcontrollers to tabbar  programatically based on iPad Device check

Comment: Use constraints in your storyboard.

Comment: @AtWork. I mean I would like to have more screens in the iPhone version than in the iPad one.

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati. I thought it would be this way. I just wanted to know if there was another way. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @OlivierNoel Unfortunately No, for that you have to handle it programmatically

Comment: @AtWork So I'll do this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking into size classes

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

It lets you design for each device size so that your app looks good on all devices and orientations.  Also have a look at constraints.  From my understanding you want to have a view controller for each size which is a really bad idea and will make your storyboard really cluttered.  Stick to 1 viewcontroller and use size classes.